# C++ float does not change when operand is smaller than 129

Tags: c++, floating-point

Here, i subtract 128.0 and 129.0 from a float variable 2M times.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdlib.h> //is this the problem? Or am i doing something wrong?
int main()
{

float d1=3.0e9;
printf("\n before: %f \n",d1);
for(int i=0;i<2000000;i++) d1=d1-128.0; //doesnt change!    
printf("\n after : %f \n",d1);
for(int i=0;i<2000000;i++) d1=d1-129.0; //does change!
printf("\n after2: %f \n",d1);

//is 129 is the minimum step for sub/add ? Isnt this wrong? 
//Is this about exponential part 10^9 ?
getchar();
return 0;
 }
```

Output:

[image]

**Question:** Why this float does not change by adding/subbing by operands smaller then 129? Because i choose the initial float value 3.0e9 ?

When i choose initial value 3.0e10, both initialization and both subtractions dont work.

When i choose initial value 3.0e8, minimum change is 17.  So 16 doesnt change. :(

So, thanks for answers, . When initial value get smaller, minimum step gets smaller according to **precision**.

VC++ 2010 express . windows xp 32 bit. pentium-m

Comment: A *screenshot* of text -- seriously???

Comment: i press printscreen and copy the file quicker than writing 3 floats

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık, you should turn on quickedit mode and use the mouse to copy the text. Or just right-click and use the menu to enter "select" mode.

Comment: Right-click the command window caption bar, and choose "Properties". There is a checkbox for quickedit mode. Select text with the left mouse button, right mouse button copies to clipboard.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this for next questions

Comment: Obligatory link to Goldberg paper: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can understand what's going on by looking at the anatomy of a [32-bit float](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision). The value `3.0E9` in IEEE754 format is `0x4F32D05E`, with exponent value 31 (you can use [this online calculator](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html) to find the value).

Now we have 23 sub-unity binary digits left for the mantissa. That means that the smallest increment, i.e. the difference between to adjacent values of the mantissa, is a number with binary scale 31 − 23 = 8. Since 128 is 2<sup>7</sup>, we see that it is just small enough to fall off the end of the mantissa, while 129 is large enough to be visible.

Answer (score 5):

It's because your initial value. A float can hold only a small amount of digits, so it cannot represent the result of the operation and it rounds it to the closest value.

Answer (score 5):

Use `double` instead of `float`.

Then learn about the concept of "precision".

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Type `float` is good for approximately 9 decimal places. A full description of 32bit float is here:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Thank you for your generous answer